# Facial Landmark Detection using Dlib

Tags: computer-vision, face-detection, keypoint, dlib

Is it possible to use [train_shape_predictor_ex.cpp.html](http://dlib.net/train_shape_predictor_ex.cpp.html) and [face_landmark_detection_ex.cpp.html](http://dlib.net/face_landmark_detection_ex.cpp.html) to training with different landmark numbers? Both detect `68` landmarks in a frontal face by default. I would like to detect `39` landmarks only. I can train all right using the `train_shape_predictor_ex`. however `face_landmark_detection_ex` outputs the attached message:

**exception thrown**

```
Error detected at line 25. 
Error detected in file /Users/Vareto/Documents/Dlib/dlib/../dlib/image_processing/render_face_detections.h.
Error detected in function std::vector dlib::render_face_detections(const std::vector &, const dlib::rgb_pixel).
Failing expression was dets[i].num_parts() == 68.
std::vector render_face_detections()
Invalid inputs were given to this function.
dets[0].num_parts(): 39
```

Comment: How  did you train train_shape_predictor_ex.cpp. can you elaborate me. I am also looking for this.

Comment: @VIctor, I used a computer vision library called Dlib: http://dlib.net. You must compile the examples they made available. In order to do so, you must download it and follow the website instructions.

Comment: How did you get training_with_face_landmarks.xml for the dataset, you are using.

Comment: You can annotate it yourself, but since I'm working with 68 landmarks it would take forever. So, I used TCDCN ( http://mmlab.ie.cuhk.edu.hk/projects/TCDCN.html). 
Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of error messages this one is pretty clear.

It's saying that while you've got `39` markers (congrats on training it!), the demo is still trying to draw `68` in the `render_face_detections()` function.

```
39 != 68
```

Comment: You were right! With your advice I made it work. Thanks

Comment: @RafaelHenrique, great stuff, I did the same thing  :D. Have fun with it!

Comment: @LamarLatrell can U provide me details about `training_with_face_landmarks.xml` how to create it .I have created xml file using imglab but I don't know to insert landmarks points in it for each image.

Comment: @VIctor, ask a well researched and coherent question on the SO site and not only may I help you, but others may too.

Comment: @LamarLatrell  It may be very helpful if you please answer this question [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36711905/dlib-train-shape-predictor-ex-cpp)