# DLib : train_shape_predictor_ex.cpp

Tags: c++, face-detection, training-data, dlib

I am trying to train the shape predictor of Dlib by executing [train_dlib_shape_predictor_ex.cpp](http://dlib.net/train_shape_predictor_ex.cpp.html) on [helen dataset](http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~vuongle2/helen/) as described in the code, I place test images in a face folder in current directory of shape predictor. But when I run the code it throws following exception:

```
C:\train_shape_predictor_ex\Release>train_shape_predictor_ex test

exception thrown!
ERROR: unable to open test/training_with_face_landmarks.xml for reading.
```

as no `training_with_face_landmarks.xml` and `testing_with_face_landmarks.xml` files are available in helen dataset on the following page : [link](http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~vuongle2/helen/)

There is a folder named annotation which contains one text file containing the 194 landmark points location for each and every image in the dataset. How to convert this file into `training_with_face_landmarks.xml`.

Comment: I think you have to label them yourself. DLib has a helpful tool for this: https://github.com/davisking/dlib/tree/master/tools/imglab

Comment: @Moreira annotation folder contains separate file for each image. so how should I make one `training_with_face_landmarks.xml`

Comment: You have two options: either you ignore the annotation folder and use the DLib tool to manually label your images (read the README.txt on the site in my previous comments), or you have to map the coordinates in the annotations to the coordinates needed by the `training_with_face_landmarks.xml`. However, this file needs additional data such as bounding boxes, which I don't think you can get from the annotations file.

Comment: @Moreira I have compiled dlib and examples using visual studio. can u tell me how can I compile imglab using visual studio.

Comment: @Moreira Ok I have compiled imglab and got the bounding box of each image in the xml file . Can u tell me how to add landmark points in this xml file for each image.

Comment: If I recall I built the .xml file myself - I used a plugin for adobe illustrator to output the point data (that I had drawn). The output was just text and so is an .xml file, so I just processed (i.e. wrote my own code) to convert the illustator plugin file to the require xml format. It worked, but was a rather dull side project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up the 'training_with_face_landmarks.xml' file and observe its structure.

Now, ask yourself:

1. What changes between files? (hint: the point data)
2. What stays the same? (hint: generic 'boiler plate' top and tail)

Open up the HELEN data - ask the same again...

Your task now is to parse the data from the HELEN set into a temporary data-structure/variable and then write it to file with all the required top and tail. It'll be a kludge and likely annoying to write with loops inside loops inside loops etc. but you'll get there.

'c++ i/o streams' as a search string will get you started.

Comment: I do not get any *training_with_face_landmarks.xml* file in **helen** dataset.

Comment: If I give bounding box for each object in every image may vary the detection box for images

Comment: @VIctor, I mean open up the sample .xml you already have. What I'm saying is you've got to reverse engineer this. It's what I did, at least.

Comment: Hey @LamarLatrell, when doing the conversion from helen to dlib's format, did you just deduct the bounding box from the 68 points set (min, max etc)?

Answer (score 10):

I created the training_with_face_landmarks.xml for helen training images (part 1, 2, 3, & 4) of total 2000 images.

Download Link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jk98moqm8vopp5b/training_with_face_landmarks_2000.zip?dl=0

Steps:

1. Download  Train images - part 1, Train images - part 2, Train images - part 3 & Train images - part 4 from http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~vuongle2/helen/. (each part has 500 images, so total of 2000 images)
2. Place all the images & the training_with_face_landmarks.xml in a common folder (Ex: Folder name "train").
3. In the project train_shape_predictor_ex.cpp, comment out these sections/lines

   a. Reference to testing_with_face_landmarks.xml and its usage 
   b. trainer set_oversampling_amount(100)
   c. trainer set_nu(0.05)
   d. trainer set_tree_depth(3)
4. Set command line argument as ./train
5. Run the project
6. It will generate sp.dat of size approx 178 MB (took 2 hours approx in my laptop)
7. Use this sp.dat file in face_landmark_detection_ex project 
   Command line Ex: sp.dat Example_image.jpg
8. In face_landmark_detection_ex.cpp, 
   a. In a loop of 194, call draw_solid_circle function 
   b. using save_png function save the landmark output as a file.

Enjoy :)

Regards
Gopi. J

Comment: Updated with testing_with_face_landmarks.xml as well as the 194 point dat file.  link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/t5h024w0xkedq0j/AABS3GprqIvb_PwqeHOn2dxNa?dl=0

Comment: step 9: code to print landmark numbers instead of circle:

{
 Mat buff_img;
 buff_img = toMat(img);
 int k;

 for (k = 0; k < 194; ++k)
 {
  putText(buff_img, std::to_string(k), cvPoint(shape.part(k).x(), shape.part(k).y()),
   FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 0.5, cvScalar(255, 255, 0), 1, CV_AA);
 }
 save_png(img, "outImage.png");
}

Comment: possibly the best answer ever!

Comment: This saves a lot of work and time. I compared the HELEN annotation files with the training_with_face_landmarks.xml. The differences are that the HELEN annotations have subpixel (float) accuracy which are left out in the landmarks file meaning it has pixel (integer with the comma omitted, not rounded) accuracy. And one has to probably change the image paths inside the landmarks.xml. Nevertheless, great work!