# How to create `testing.xml` file for dlib training?

Tags: python, c++, xml, training-data, dlib

I am trying to train an face detector using **Dlib**. I selected 300 images for training. I have used the **Imglab** tool to draw the bounding boxes across the images.And I have created `traing.xml` file.

But I don't understand,

- How to create `testing.xml` file?
- Which type of data store in `testing.xml` file?

Please someone help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'll suggest you to have a look on following answers

- [DLib : train_shape_predictor_ex.cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36711905/453767)

Steps to train shape detector

1. Place all the images & the training_with_face_landmarks.xml(training.xml in your case) in a common folder (Ex: Folder name "train").
2. In the project train_shape_predictor_ex.cpp, comment out these sections/lines

   1. Reference to testing_with_face_landmarks.xml and its usage
   2. trainer set_oversampling_amount(100)
   3. trainer set_nu(0.05)
   4. trainer set_tree_depth(3)
3. Set command line argument as ./train
4. Run the project: It will generate sp.dat of size approx 178 MB (min 16gb RAM is required)
5. Use this sp.dat file in face_landmark_detection_ex project Command line Ex: sp.dat Example_image.jpg

**training vs testing file**

Both files are having similar structure and may have same data. You use `training.xml` to train the shape detector, and `testing.xml` (which may be duplicate but better to contain different face details) to verify if shape detector (face detector in this case) is detecting the shape as given in testing.xml.